# UIWebview re-enables scrolling even after scrollEnabled is set to NO

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Here is a problem. I am using a draggable image in UIWebview. The Source code: here:http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-7/

It simply disables the scrolling during drag and reenable it when the dragging is completed.

It works perfectly fine when UIWebview is first brought up and hereafter. As soon as the edited text length is longer than the screen. UIWebview ignores the scroll setting of its scrollview and re-enables the scrolling.

The way I disable the scroll view is using this:

```
    webview.scrollview.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Please tell me where I was wrong. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused because of the following wrap placed within the html file I loaded as a template editing section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {
margin: 0;
}
#wrap {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#content 
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Any div wrapped with this block will always allow itself to be scrolled.
Deleted it and things turned out to function properly again!

Answer (score 0):

may use

```
for(UIView *aView in webview.subviews){
    if([aView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
                aView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

this makes sure that any `scrollview`'s scrolling is disabled.

Comment: I have solved this problem. It is because in my template file for rich text editing. I set an overflow wrap to the div. That is basically a wrap make the scrollview always allow scrolling. If you want to see the code block. You can ask me.